# Behaviour of new and malloc in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In C, it is [considered poor form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to typecast the result of a call to `malloc`. However, it seems that the result of calls to `malloc` in C++ *should* be typecast, even though both `malloc` and `new` have return type `void*` and calls to `new` are not typecast. Is there a reason why in C++ the void pointer returned by `new` is automatically promoted while the void pointer returned by `malloc` isn't?

Comment: I think it is because `new` is a keyword, but `malloc()` is not a keyword, I don't know surely. +1 vote

Comment: Part of your confusion (btw, it is _must_ cast, not _should_ for C++) comes from the fact that C is much more lax about pointer types. It is allowable (and indeed well-defined) to assing `void*` to any pointer type. In C++, you would consider this approach "broken", because they are pointers of different types, so it isn't meaningful to assign one to the other. Though, funnily, C++ explicitly allows for that exact same invalid conversion from no-type to some-type with the zero literal and with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are confusing `operator new` with the `new` operator. `operator new` just allocates raw memory and returns a `void*`, whereas `new T` also calls the constructor after allocation and returns a `T*`.

Also, you have to cast the result of `malloc` in C++, because unlike C, C++ does not allow implicit conversions from `void*` to other pointer types. Note that `void*` is used very rarely in C++.

Comment: "*Note that `void*` is used very rarely in C++.*" That ought to be "should be", not "is". I've seen highly unpleasant amounts of `void*` use in C++ code.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, memory locations are indeed expressed through void pointers. But memory isn't the same as objects. An object *needs* memory in order to live, but the object is distinct from the memory in which it resides.

You need to *create an object* in the memory. If you will, the `new`-operator "converts" between memory and objects:

```
#include <cstdlib>

void * pm = std::malloc(sizeof(int));       // C-style
void * qm = ::operator new(sizeof(int));    // C++-style

int * po = ::new (pm) int(10);              // void pointer goes in...
int * qo = ::new (qm) int(20);              // ...object pointer comes out.

// (... class-type objects would need to be destroyed...)

std::free(pm);
::operator delete(qm);
```